# How to add two toolbars over keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, textview, uitoolbar

I'm able to add a single toolbar over keyboard but i don't know how to add two consecutive toolbars over keyboard for single textView.

I'm able to add one tool bar just like below

[image]

But i want to do just like the below attachment.

[image]

Comment: Did you use storyboard to add the toolbar?

Comment: no i did it programmatically. I can post code if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in way of doing this. You will need to roll your own `UIView` /  `UIToolbar` and place it above the keyboards first `UIToolBar` - you can use the system notifications to listen to UIKeyboard events and the adjust the second `UIToolbar`'s frame property accordingly.

Comment: won't it be bit complex to handle.

Comment: Not too complex no. But then again, you're wanting functionality that doesn't exist with built in methods, so you will need to get your hands a little bit dirty. ;)

Answer (score -2):

You can use `UIToolbar` and customize it to add your buttons into it. You can add buttons like this.

```
  -(void)addToolBarOnKeyBordOnTextField:(UITextView *)textview
{
    if (!viewToolbar) {
        viewToolbar = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 110)];
        [viewToolbar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        UIToolbar * numberToolbar1 = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
        numberToolbar1.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
        numberToolbar1.translucent = YES;

        UIButton *buttonTopLeft = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 50)];
        [buttonTopLeft setTitle:@"Clear" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [numberToolbar1 addSubview:buttonTopLeft];

        UIButton *buttonTopRight = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width - 60, 0, 60, 50)];
        [buttonTopRight setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [numberToolbar1 addSubview:buttonTopRight];

        [viewToolbar addSubview:numberToolbar1];

        UIToolbar *numberToolbar2 = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60,self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
        numberToolbar2.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
        numberToolbar2.translucent = YES;

        UIButton *buttonBottomLeft = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 50)];
        [buttonBottomLeft setTitle:@"Clear" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [numberToolbar2 addSubview:buttonBottomLeft];

        UIButton *buttonBottomRight = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width - 60, 0, 60, 50)];
        [buttonBottomRight setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [numberToolbar2 addSubview:buttonBottomRight];

        [viewToolbar addSubview:numberToolbar2];


    }
    [textview setInputAccessoryView:viewToolbar];

}
```

Remember to call this method in `textViewShouldBeginEditing`. You can add remaining buttons and set the frames as done in code.

Comment: I think you didn't get my question. I want to add multiple toolbars not multiple Items over one toolbar :)

Comment: Even the updated code does not address the OP's question as you're still adding one  UIToolBar to the keyboard. He wants to add more than one tool bar to the keyboard. Not buttons.

Comment: @aqsaarshad I don't think there is any standard way to do this. I only told the way you can achieve this functionality, anyway thanks.